# How do I find the size of the array in go

Tags: arrays, go

I have tried `len()` function but it gives the declared value. The `size()` function gives an error.

Code:

```
package main
var check [100]int
func main() {
    println(len(check))
}
```

The output is `100` here, I need the total items in array (i.e. `0`).

Comment: it's not C, in Go the elements of array are initialized.

Comment: What else than 100 could `len` return for an array of length 100?

Comment: Please do the go tour. It's fun I promise. https://tour.golang.org/

Comment: @Volker, actually he want to say the actual number of elements in array. In java if we declare `List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(10);` and print `a.size()` then it gives 0 and if we add two element using `a.add()` and check for `a.size()` it will give size 2. consider this Go program https://play.golang.org/p/Zc6sFI8wAl, read comments below the program which describes problem

Comment: @Volker If your program changes, would you like to manually change 100 to 101 in a thousand places, or just in one place?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Arrays in Go are fixed sizes: once you create an array in Go, you can't change its size later on. This is so to an extent that the length of an array is part of the array type (this means the types `[2]int` and `[3]int` are 2 distinct types). That being said the length of a value of some array type is always the same, and it is determined by its type. For example the length of an array value of type `[100]int` is always `100`, (which can be queried using the built-in function [`len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len)).

[Spec: Array Types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types)

> The length is part of the array's type; it must evaluate to a non-negative [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) representable by a value of type `int`. The length of array `a` can be discovered using the built-in function [len](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity).

If you're looking for the answer to "How many elements have been set?", that is not tracked in Go. The "total items in array" you're looking for is also always the same as the array length: when you create an array in Go, all elements in the array are initialized to the [zero-value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the element's type (unless otherwise specified e.g. by using a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)).

For example after this line:

```
var arr [100]int
```

The array `arr` already has 100 `int`s, all being `0` (because that is the zero-value of type `int`). After the following line:

```
var arr2 = [3]int{1, 2, 3}
```

The array `arr2` has 3 `int` elements, being `1`, `2` and `3`. And after the following line

```
var arr3 = [...]bool{3: true}
```

The array `arr3` has 4 `bool` elements, being `false`, `false`, `false` and `true` (`false` is the zero value of type `bool` and we only specified the 4th element to be `true` which is at index `3`).

Your question might have more meaning if you would ask about [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types):

> A slice is a descriptor for a contiguous segment of an *underlying array* and provides access to a numbered sequence of elements from that array.

So basically a slice is a "view" of some (contiguous) part of an array. A slice header or descriptor contains a pointer to the first value of the part it describes in the array, it contains a length and the capacity (which is the max value to which the length can be extended).

I really recommend to read the following blog posts:

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[The Go Blog: Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

Comment: In this case consider a scenario where I want to write logic depending upon elements in array. consider this Go program https://play.golang.org/p/Zc6sFI8wAl, read comments added below the program which will describe my problem.

Comment: @Amogh 2 things: First, you're not changing anything in the array as that code is also commented out. Second, if you do change some elements but not all, there will still be some elements being 0. And if you change other elements to be positives, the minimum / lowest will still be the 0, so that is the correct output.

Comment: Yes, perfect I got that. so that means there is noting like in Go to check whether elements are added or not in an array/slice. Because don't consider the simple progrm to find smallest number. consider a service method which finds some Ids of somthing from DB and adds in array/slice and next we iterate over that array to perform somthing. In that case if IDs are not found by first process then also second process will iterate over with value 0, right?

Comment: Like, what we do in java, we declare List of int as `List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);` and adds some Id's in it using `a.add()` now consider I have added only 10 Ids and started a for loop till i<a.size() this will iterate only for 0-9 as a.size() is 10. But in Go we consider the same senario then it will iterate for 100 times. and moreover main concern is in Go we cannot check whether an array\slice has elements added or not. This may cause performance cost in DB operations cause we are unable to check "actual" size of elements in array\slice. dont you feel the same?

Comment: What I feel, we should NOT use array representation where we want to check how many elements are actually added in it. We should use slice by declaring `len` as 0 for eg. `var  aList = make([]int,0,100)` by this `len(aList)` gives so we can check if elements are really added or not.

Comment: @Amogh Arrays have their uses. Check out this answer: [Why have arrays in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645175/why-have-arrays-in-go/38645895#38645895) If that doesn't answer your question, post it as a new question.