# Different sizes of arrays using make or default initialization

Tags: arrays, go, initialization, slice

I'm new to Go and try to understand the language in order to write efficient code. In the following code, sizes of the two arrays differ by 140%, can someone explain this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    ind1 := make([]bool, 10)
    var ind2 [10]bool
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(ind1)) // 24
    fmt.Println(len(ind1)) // 10
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(ind2)) // 10
    fmt.Println(len(ind2)) // 10
}
```

The size of the first array remains 10, even in case the capacity is set explicitly:

```
    ind1 := make([]bool, 10, 10)
```

Can someone explain this? Is there any additional overhead in using `make`? If yes, why is it recommended to use make over default initialization?

Comment: The first thing when learning Go is to work through the Tour of Go (https://tour.golang.org). The second thing is to do it again. The third thing is reading Effective Go (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html). The fourth thing is reading the Spec (https://golang.org/ref/spec). Then you redo the tour and then you worry about efficient code. Not earlier :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Arrays](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) and [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) in Go are different things.

Your `ind1` is a slice, and `ind2` is an array. The length of an array is part of the type, so for example `[2]bool` and `[3]bool` are 2 different array types.

A slice in Go is a descriptor for a *contiguous segment* of an underlying array and provides access to a numbered sequence of elements from that array. This slice header is a struct-like data structure represented by the type [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader):

```
type SliceHeader struct {
        Data uintptr
        Len  int
        Cap  int
}
```

It contains a data pointer (to the first element of the represented segment), a length and a capacity.

The [`unsafe.SizeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof) function returns the size in bytes of the hypothetical variable as if it would hold the passed value. **It does not include any memory possibly referenced by it.**

So if you pass a slice value (`ind1`), it will tell you the size of the above mentioned *slice header*. Note that the size of the fields of `SliceHeader` are architecture dependent, e.g. `int` may be 4 bytes on one platform and it may be 8 bytes on another. The size `24` applies to 64-bit architectures.

The Go Playground runs on a 32-bit architecture. Let's see this example:

```
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(make([]bool, 10)))
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(make([]bool, 20)))

fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof([10]bool{}))
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof([20]bool{}))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/en0A1y0uUD)):

```
12
12
10
20
```

As you can see, no matter the length of the slice you pass to `unsafe.SizeOf()`, it always returns 12 on the Go Playground (and 24 on 64-bit architectures).

On the other hand, an array value includes all its elements, and as such, its size depends on its length. Size of `[10]bool` is 10, and size of `[20]bool` is 20.

See related questions+answers to learn more about slices, arrays and the difference and relation between them:

[How do I find the size of the array in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937828/how-do-i-find-the-size-of-the-array-in-go/35939008#35939008)

[Why have arrays in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645175/why-have-arrays-in-go/38645895#38645895)

[Why use arrays instead of slices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694652/why-use-arrays-instead-of-slices)

Must read blog posts:

[Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

Answer (score 1):

`ind1` is a slice (the type is `[]bool`).

`ind2` is an array (the type is `[10]bool`).

They are not of the same type.

The result of `unsafe.Sizeof(ind1)` probably has nothing to do with the arguments passed to `make`.