# How to pass array to a GO function without define the size of the array?

Tags: arrays, go

I try to defined an array pass it to the function that doesn't define the size of the argument, errors occur however.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a=[5]int{1,2,3,4,5}
    f(a,5)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
func f(arr []int,size int) {
    for i,x:=range arr  {
        fmt.Println(i,x)
        arr[i]=100
    }
}
```

cannot use a (type [5]int) as type []int in argument to f

Comment: One cannot pass an array without defining size. For such cases one needs to use slices.Use of arrays is very limited in GoLang.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't you put a variable as a multidimensional array size in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809499/why-cant-you-put-a-variable-as-a-multidimensional-array-size-in-go/46809576?r=SearchResults#46809576)

Comment: Do you want something like that? https://play.golang.org/p/Tko8AP36ukH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the array to a slice inline, like so:

```
f(a[:],5)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/skm4DsDwR9I)

For more background see: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals